# STL Iterator for nested containers (such as vector<vector<T> >)

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, stdvector

Recently I had to replace a single container with a collection of similar containers. As a result, I needed a combined iterator retaining the semantics of the original iterator.
The problem that I ran into was the handling of the combined `end()` position.

Without the ability to compare unassigned iterators, I had to include all four iterators as members (i.e. the two ranges, external and internal). This resulted in `operator==()` requiring three comparisons in the most common case. This, of course, is much worse than comparison in the ordinary nested loops (which require a single comparison in the most common case). Beside that, I noticed that the four iterator code is prone to errors, because keeping the `end()` iterators in the combined iterator may lead to skipping the exit condition of the `for()` loop if container contents changes inside the loop.

Here is a sketch of the code I used:

```
   template <class T>
   class MyContainer
   {
      typedef std::vector<T> Inner;
      typedef std::vector<Inner> Outer;
      Outer v_;
   public:
      class iterator
      {
         friend class MyContainer;
         Outer::iterator it1_, it1end_;
         Inner::iterator it2_, it2end_;
         iterator(Outer::iterator it1, Outer::iterator it1end) :
            it1_(it1), it1end_(it1end)
         {
            if(it1_!=it1end_) {
               it2_ = it1_->begin();
               it2end_ = it1_->end();
            }
         }
      public:
         bool operator==(iterator it) const {
            return it1_==it.it1_ &&
               (it1_==it1end_ || it2_==it.it2_);
         }
      };
      
      iterator begin() { return iterator(v_.begin(), v_.end()); }
      iterator end() { return iterator(v_.end(), v_.end()); }
   };
```

Taking into account these considerations, is there a way to implement the nested iterator semantics without having to store both `end()` values or without the need to have three comparisons in the `operator==()`?

Comment: What about [iterating encapsulated nested STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667176/iterating-encapsulated-nested-stl-containers?rq=1)?

Comment: Thanks! I followed the link and found a 'flattening_iterator' example. It looks nice and familiar, and the problems are still there. It requires storing three iterators and doing four (!) comparisons in the most common case in every for() loop iteration. Looks like we can't keep the external semantics _and_ retain the original efficiency.

Comment: If you are treating two different containers as the same container, perhaps you should find a way to make the two types the same, so that all the data can coexist in the same container.  That will most likely involve creating a new type(possibly using inheritance).

Comment: I understand your approach, but in my situation I need to actually split the original container to get hashed access while populating and sequential access while reading the results.

Comment: You might also want to read Matt Austern's old paper on [Segmented Iterators](http://lafstern.org/matt/segmented.pdf). Rather than flattening the range to work with existing code, this uses tag dispatching to allow a generic algorithm to work with the segmented structure. It doesn't, however, allow you to maintain the entire change in one place like a flattening iterator does.

Comment: Very interesting, never heard of such iterators. Thanks for the link!