# How to flatten iterators of nested containers?

Tags: c++, iterator

This is (yet) a(nother) follow up to James' answer to this question: [Flattening iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623082/flattening-iterator/3623597)

How do I alter the flattenig_iterator such that it works recursively? Say I have more levels of nested containers and I don't want to be limited to a given nesting depth. I.e. flattening_iterator should work with

```
std::vector< std::vector < std::vector < int > > >
```

as well as with

```
std::vector< std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < int > > > >
```

In my actual code I have an array of objects which might or not contain such an array themselves.

**edit**:

After playing around with different ways of iterating through different kind of nested containers I learned something that might be interesting to others as well:

Accessing the container elements with nested loops executed 5 to 6 times faster than with the iterator solution.

Pros:

- elements can be complex objects, e.g. (like in my case) classes that contain containers.
- faster execution

Cons:

- Each container structure requires a new implementation of the loop
- standard library algorithms are not available

Other pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so this isn't a full solution - but I ran out of time. So this currently implements not a full iterator but a cut down iterator-like class which defines something like this interface, and requires C++11. I've tested it on g++4.7:

```
template<typename NestedContainerType, typename Terminator>
class flatten_iterator
{
    bool complete();
    void advance();
    Terminator& current();
};
```

Where `NestedContainerType` is the nested container type (surprisingly), and Terminator is the type of the innermost thing that you're wanting to get out of the flatten.

The code below works, but this is certainly not extensively tested. Wrapping it up fully (assuming you're happy with forward advance only) shouldn't be too much work, in particular if you use [`boost::iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iterator/doc/facade-and-adaptor.html#iterator-facade).

```
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

template<typename ContainerType, typename Terminator>
class flatten_iterator
{
public:
    typedef flatten_iterator<typename ContainerType::value_type, Terminator> inner_it_type;
    typedef typename inner_it_type::value_type value_type;

    flatten_iterator() {}
    
    flatten_iterator( ContainerType& container ) : m_it( container.begin() ), m_end( container.end() )
    {
        skipEmpties();
    }
    
    bool complete()
    {
        return m_it == m_end;
    }
    
    value_type& current()
    {
        return m_inner_it.current();
    }
    
    void advance()
    {
        if ( !m_inner_it.complete() )
        {
            m_inner_it.advance();
        }
        if ( m_inner_it.complete() )
        {
            ++m_it;
            skipEmpties();
        }
    }
    
private:
    void skipEmpties()
    {
        while ( !complete() )
        {
            m_inner_it = inner_it_type(*m_it);
            if ( !m_inner_it.complete() ) break;
            ++m_it;
        }
    }

private:
    inner_it_type                    m_inner_it;
    typename ContainerType::iterator m_it, m_end;
};


template<template<typename, typename ...> class ContainerType, typename Terminator, typename ... Args>
class flatten_iterator<ContainerType<Terminator, Args...>, Terminator>
{
public:
    typedef typename ContainerType<Terminator, Args...>::value_type value_type;
    
public:
    flatten_iterator() {}
    
    flatten_iterator( ContainerType<Terminator, Args...>& container ) :
        m_it( container.begin() ), m_end( container.end() )
    {
    }
    
    bool complete()
    {
        return m_it == m_end;
    }
    
    value_type& current() { return *m_it; }
    void advance() { ++m_it; }
    
private:
    typename ContainerType<Terminator, Args...>::iterator m_it, m_end;
};
```

And with the following test cases, it does what you would expect:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{   
    typedef std::vector<int> n1_t;
    typedef std::vector<std::deque<short> > n2_t;
    typedef std::list<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > > > n4_t;
    typedef std::vector<std::deque<std::vector<std::deque<std::vector<std::list<float> > > > > > n6_t;
    
    n1_t n1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    n2_t n2 = { {}, { 1, 2 }, {3}, {}, {4}, {}, {} };
    n4_t n4 = { { { {1.0}, {},  {}, {2.0}, {} }, { {}, {} }, { {3.0} } }, { { { 4.0 } } } };
    n6_t n6 = { { { { { {1.0f}, {},  {}, {2.0f}, {} }, { {}, {} }, { {3.0f} } }, { { { 4.0f } } } } } };
    
    flatten_iterator<n1_t, int> i1( n1 );
    while ( !i1.complete() )
    {
        std::cout << i1.current() << std::endl;
        i1.advance();
    }
    
    flatten_iterator<n2_t, short> i2( n2 );
    while ( !i2.complete() )
    {
        std::cout << i2.current() << std::endl;
        i2.advance();
    }
    
    flatten_iterator<n4_t, double> i4( n4 );
    while ( !i4.complete() )
    {
        std::cout << i4.current() << std::endl;
        i4.advance();
    }
    
    flatten_iterator<n6_t, float> i6( n6 );
    while ( !i6.complete() )
    {
        std::cout << i6.current() << std::endl;
        i6.advance();
    }
}
```

So prints the following for each of the container types:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Note that it doesn't yet work with `set`s because there's some foo required to deal with the fact that `set` iterators return const references. Exercise for the reader... :-)

Comment: wow. looks good, works, very close to what I need. One remark: I try to use as little libraries as necessary. So is the `boost::scoped_ptr` really necessary?

Comment: The `scoped_ptr` is totally not necessary. Just store the iterator by value.

Comment: ??? I guess I'm making a stupid mistake, but the line `typename inner_it_type m_inner_it;` give the compiler error `expected nested-name-specifier before ‘inner_it_type’`

Comment: No `typename` needed (actually, it's forbidden) if there are no `::`.

Comment: renmoving `typename` yields a meter of error messages, the first being: `no matching function for call to ‘flatten_iterator<std::deque<short int>, short int>::flatten_iterator()’`. Another one states that `m_inner_it` is not of a pointer type

Comment: Sorry guys. Been away from a PC. I'll be back at the computer tomorrow morning my time (GMT) and will have a go at fixing it up for you. Are you using g++ 4.7? If not, let me know which compiler and I'll work it through.

Comment: I'm not storing `inner_it` by value in this example because in the current way its set up, if the outer container is completely empty, initialising an `inner_it` will try to call `begin()` and `end()` on an invalid outer iterator (`end()`). But you can replace the `scoped_ptr` with appropriate `new`/`delete` pairs, or perhaps it can be re-worked not to need the dynamic allocation at all. This is just the first thing I got working, so by no means an optimal design. Open to all suggestions.

Comment: And to compile, g++4.7.0 (in my case) requires the `-std=gnu++11` option.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I compiled with the 0x flag elre<ady. I am using 4.6.3 but I have a 4.7 checked out, so I will try it as soon as I get to the office (GMT+1 ;) )

Comment: Great.  But pls get rid of the (scoped) pointers, and pls use pre-increment when writing iterators and not using the returnvalue.

Comment: @steffen. Ok: scoped_ptr removed, pre-increment instead of post-increment (thanks xtofl) and the advance logic tidied up and some redundancy removed. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Alex: Not for my current problem, because I actually have an array of objects which /sometimes/ contain another array of the same objects. But I learned a lot about iterators and saved this for future use ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I'll quickly outline a solution:

1. Write a `is_container` trait that detects `begin()` and `end()` members, or possibly some more complex rules;
2. Write a `all_flattening_iterator<T>` template that is just a `flattening_iterator<all_flattening_iterator<typename T::value_type>>`;
3. Write a specialization of `all_flattening_iterator<T>` for when `T` is not a container (use a default template `bool` parameter) that is just a regular iterator.

Comment: probably variadic templates may provide a more convenient way to use the proposed `is_container` metafunction.

Comment: @xtofl how are variadic templates helpful here? There's only one template parameter involved.

Comment: I was dreaming of a way to use `list` and `dequeue` and everything with a `begin` and `end` in one go :)

Comment: @xtoff: His proposed solution can do that

Comment: @(the person who downvoted this answer): Please comment on what you think is wrong with this answer, so that we can learn something and the auther can correct his/her answer. Thank you

Comment: @Martinho: Could you please elaborate on your solutions?

Comment: @Martinho: no hurry ;-) I'll check back later. Thanks

Comment: @steffen: 8 years later and Martinho is still elaborating :-P just kidding, great answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I arrive a little late here, but I have just published [a library (multidim)](https://github.com/AlbertoMarnetto/multidim) to deal with such problem. Check out [my answer to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34843867/2453661) for details.

My solution takes inspiration from [Alex Wilson's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456880/2453661) of using "telescopically nested" iterators. It adds some more functionality though (e.g. support for read-only container such as `set`s, backwards iteration, random access) and offers a more pleasant interface, as it auto-detects the type of the "leaf" elements.

Comment: Multidim seems to have problems though. I tried:
vector<vector<vector<uint32_t> > > tst; auto fw = multidim::makeFlatView(tst); Unfortunately this fails to compile with VC2017.

Comment: @fhw72 Interesting. Unfortunately I have not worked on the library for a long time and I do not have a Windows machine any more. However, if you open an issue in my repo I can have a look at the matter when I find the time.