# C++ iterator_adapter over collection of vectors

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flattening iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623082/flattening-iterator)

I have a vector of vectors of some type (say int). I would like to iterate
over the collection of elements in the vectors, pretty much like iterating
over a vector of ints.

I can implement something that does this but was wondering how to use boost's
iterator_adapter to do this.

Comment: No it's not. Author is not asking how to implement it all by him self but is asking if it is possible to resue something from iterator_adapter.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question specifically talks about `boost::iterator_adaptor`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I hacked up. It works and outputs the correct result, but has a lot of work to be done.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

template <typename Iter>
class flattening_iterator :
    public boost::iterator_adaptor<
                flattening_iterator<Iter>,
                Iter,
                typename Iter::value_type::iterator::value_type,
                boost::forward_traversal_tag,
                typename Iter::value_type::iterator::value_type
    >
{
private:
        using super_t = boost::iterator_adaptor<
                                flattening_iterator<Iter>,
                                Iter,
                                typename Iter::value_type::iterator::value_type,
                                boost::forward_traversal_tag,
                                typename Iter::value_type::iterator::value_type
                        >;
        using inner_iterator = typename Iter::value_type::iterator;
public:
        flattening_iterator(Iter it)
                : super_t(it),
                  inner_begin(),
                  inner_end(),
                  outer_end(it)
        {}
        flattening_iterator(Iter begin, Iter end)
                : super_t(begin),
                  inner_begin((*begin).begin()),
                  inner_end((*begin).end()),
                  outer_end(end)
        {}
    using value_type = typename Iter::value_type::iterator::value_type;
private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    inner_iterator inner_begin;
    inner_iterator inner_end;
    Iter outer_end;

    void increment()
    {
        if (this->base_reference() == outer_end)
            return; // At the end

        ++inner_begin;
        if (inner_begin == inner_end)
        {
            ++this->base_reference();
            inner_begin = (*this->base_reference()).begin();
            inner_end = (*this->base_reference()).end();
        }
    }

    value_type dereference() const
    {
        return *inner_begin;
    }
};

template <typename Iter>
auto flatten(Iter it) -> flattening_iterator<Iter>
{
    return flattening_iterator<Iter>(it);
}

template <typename Iter>
auto flatten(Iter begin, Iter end) -> flattening_iterator<Iter>
{
    return flattening_iterator<Iter>(begin, end);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    for (auto i = flatten(v1.begin(), v1.end()); i != flatten(v1.end()); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v2{{"Hello", "Print"}, {"Me", "Here"}};
    std::copy(flatten(v2.begin(), v2.end()), flatten(v2.end()),
                  std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
}
```