# C++ list in list

Tags: c++, list, iteration

I have two lists

```
list<int> s;
list<std::list<int>> q;
```

and I did the following assignment

```
q.push_front(s);
```

How can I display the contents of q since this

```
for (q_iterator = q.begin(); q_iterator != q.end(); ++q_iterator)
    for (s_iterator = q_iterator.begin(); s_iterator != q_iterator.end(); ++s_iterator)
        cout << *s_iterator;
```

gives me an error?

Comment: `q_iterator->begin();` a.s.o.

Comment: The error here may be obvious to experienced developers but in general this question is not up to standards because it does not contain enough information (the error message!). As an aside, note that you can generalize this type of access with a [flattening iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3623082/50079)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write the following way

```
for (q_iterator = q.begin(); q_iterator != q.end(); ++q_iterator)
    for (s_iterator = q_iterator->begin(); s_iterator != q_iterator->end(); ++s_iterator)
        cout << *s_iterator;
```

or the following way

```
for (q_iterator = q.begin(); q_iterator != q.end(); ++q_iterator)
    for (s_iterator = ( *q_iterator ).begin(); s_iterator != ( *q_iterator ).end(); ++s_iterator)
        cout << *s_iterator;
```

provided that `q_iterator` and `s_iterator` are already declared. Otherwise you could write for example

```
for ( auto q_iterator = q.begin; /*...*/ )
```

Also you can use the range based for statement. For example

```
for ( const auto &s : q )
{
    for ( int x : s ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably know it, but I just want to make sure you remember about a space between angle braces.

```html
std::list<std::list<int> >
```

Comment: Oh, good to know. Thanks. Despite using C++11 I've still cared about it.