# compare nested iterators after boost transformed()

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-range, boost-adaptors

```
vector<vector<int>> input{ { { 1, 2 },{ 3, 4 } } };
auto result = input | boost::adaptors::transformed([](const auto& _) {return _; });
result.begin()->begin() == result.begin()->end();
```

If I run this w/ VS2015 with `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2`, then it fires this error in `_Compat(const _Myiter& _Right)`:

```
        _DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterators incompatible");
```

This is important because [Flattening iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623082/flattening-iterator) uses this comparison in `advance_past_empty_inner_containers()`.

What's going on? How do I fix it?

Comment: just let me know whether 1 and 2 are objects of comparison here or something else

Comment: The code is not a metaphor. 1 and 2 are integer literals.

Comment: ok since that, your code is comparing addresses !! which pushes me to wonder the point of this ??

Answer (score 2):

This returns a copy of `_`: `[](const auto& _) {return _; }`.

I haven't looked into the code, but it wouldn't surprise me at all if the iterator applies the transformation on each dereference, meaning that each time you dereference `result.begin()` (with `->`) you get a different copy of the vector. Iterators into different vectors are not comparable with each other.

Answer (score -2):

Regardless of this code's behavior that is attempting to compare **addresses**, I would suppose to initialize an iterator  `vector<vector<int>>::iterator`to simplify the procedure of comparing first and last values stored in first sub-set ,the last one should be addressed with `->rbegin()` or `->end()-1` instead of `->end()`,  which brings to an unallocated memory span.

Let me repopulate your array,
`vector<vector<int>> input{ { { 1, 2 },{ 3, 1 } } };`

You either do one of these:

```
assert(*(result.begin()->begin()) == *(result.begin()->end() - 1));
assert(*(result.begin()->begin()) == *(result.begin()->rbegin()));
```

both throw exceptions since 1=/=2

Try this:

```
assert(*(result.begin()->begin()) == *((result.end() - 1)->end() - 1));
```

It doesnt, Since foremost equals forelast stored integer.

Let me know if there is something else not talked about here or not clearly understood .