# Assigning a std::set to a 2D std::vector of ints

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, set, std

I'm trying to make a integer Matrix with no numbers repeated and its elements sorted so I was making it with a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` but then, searching on internet and Stackoverflow, I've found something called `std:set` which I see is a container and it has just the 2 properties I'm looking for: no repeated elements and sorted. Cool!

The first thing I've tried is to have that:

```
   std::vector<std::vector< std::set<int> > > Matrix;
```

But then I don't get how can I initialize it. I've tried the same way I would do with normal vectors...something like `std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix(row, std::vector<int>(col, 0));` But ofc it didn't work.

So my next idea was to have:

- A 2d vector matrix.
- A std::set with all the values

And then assign that set to the matrix so maybe will be easily for me to work with that but I'm still getting a lot of problems that I hope you can help me understanding where am I wrong...

```
int row=3,col=4;
//I create the Matrix and initialize it with 0
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix(row, std::vector<int>(col, 0));

std::set<int> SetNumbers;
for (int i = 0; i < row*col; i++)
    SetNumbers.insert((rand() % 100) + 1); // I want to random generate the 12 numbers

std::set<int>::iterator it;
for (it = SetNumbers.begin(); it != SetNumbers.end(); ++it)
    cout << "SET: "<<(*it) << endl; // Here I print on screen the numbers of the set

// Lets TRY to assign the set to the 2d vector. I use auto to avoid errors on types
for (auto it1 = Matrix.begin(); it1 != Matrix.end(); ++it1)
{
    for (auto it2 = (*it1).begin(); it2 != (*it1).end(); ++it2)
    {
        *it2 = 4; // That WORKS so maybe with the next line I get what I want...
        *it2 = SetNumbers.? // Ofc not... even intellisense doesn't work so bad way
        Matrix.assign(SetNumbers.begin(), SetNumbers.end()); // Gives Error and complains about Matrix 
         (*it2) = SetNumbers[index]; // Discovered  that set CAN't be accessed with [] 
        (*it2) = SetNumbers.begin() // Wrong too

    }
}
```

Another try I made is with function `std::copy`

```
    std::copy(SetNumbers.begin(), SetNumbers.end(), Matrix.begin());
```

But it gives me a Error 'error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes... `

And if I try to sort by rows inside the first loop with something like

```
 std::copy(SetNumbers.begin(), SetNumbers.end(), (*it1).begin());
```

Then the program crashes and I don't know what else can I try...

Thank you so much!

P.D.: Also,  another question came up... I know that using iterators is a way to avoid using the `[] operator` but could I make something like `//Cart[it1][it2].insert(number);` inside the double loop??

P.D.2:  **Clarification about Sort**

If I have numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 I want my Matrix sorted like

```
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

So I was thinking of sorting it in general which will give me a Matrix like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

And then swap positions... But maybe there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: When you say "Matrix with no numbers repeated and its elements sorted", do you mean sorted by row, by column or both?
std::vector< std::set<int> > works for sorted-by-row and sorted-by-column. Sorted-by-both, you'll need to explain a bit more how you'll enforce it.

Comment: I totally misunderstand what is a matrix with elements sorted. Could you please demonstrate it with examples?

Comment: @Jeffrey I prefer sorted by row but if its in general, its ok too. I'll put a clarification in a sec

Comment: @S.M. I've added a clarification about it :) Ty!

Comment: Maybe it is better to use linear representation of a `matrix[row][cols]` as `std::vector<int>(row * cols)`, and access an element `(i, j)` via `v[i*cols + j]`? In this case you could use std::sort algorithm.

Comment: Hi @Caleth, sorry but I don't understand you.  As u know this problem follows the one u resolved yesterday. I want a matrix with random values but sorted and that values can't be repeated so having values like 1,2,3,3 is not possible. The second3 has to be another number. Moreover, numbers are random from 1 to 100 so myMatrix can be something like 3,40,50 ...

Comment: Ignore that, I've realised where you are stuck now, see answer

Comment: @Caleth Oh! I understand you more now! I don't think I can use boost in that case so I'll talk only about map .. If I understand you right, with the map I would get 1 value per row and column (which is ok) but that value can be repeated right?

Answer (score 0):

First, by creating a `std::vector<std::vector<std::set<int>>>`, you've effectively created a *3-dimensional* construct.

Second, the problem with using nested vectors or sets is that their uniqueness isn't bound to the flattened elements -- it's bound to the nested vector/set itself. This means you would still have to check each individual element in the nested containers to make sure they're unique from the elements in their sibling containers.

You'd be better off just using a single `std::set<int>` to represent your matrix with its dimensions defined elsewhere (as you've already done with `int row=3,col=4`). One caveat: you'd have to *erase* the values you want to modify (via `std::set::erase()`) then re-insert the modified value as sets don't allow direct modification of their elements.

Using a `std::vector<int>` would work, too, but as you're aware, they aren't sorted or unique by default. That said, [it's fairly trivial to make them sorted and distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041939/697080). This would only be recommended if you aren't planning on modifying many of the values in the vector as it would really only be cost-effective to perform sorting and distinction *after* you've added all the values you wish to add. You'd have to do it again every time you modify a value which could turn into a slow mess.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is copy the values from your set into your matrix.

We can do this with `std::copy` and a [flattening iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623597/2610810)

```
std::copy(SetNumbers.begin(), SetNumbers.end(), flatten(Matrix.begin(), Matrix.end()));
```

This is also available in the [Ranges TS](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), as the `join` view

```
ranges::copy(SetNumbers, Matrix | ranges::view::join());
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way than having to make an entire class  flattening_iterator ?

Comment: *copying* an entire class. Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: True :) I've copied the Flattening into a .h file but now If I use your call of copy I get the next error and I can't understand how can I use it even deprecated: `error C4996: 'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators' ` I'm on a Win10 VS 2017

Comment: You have compile settings that are too conservative: it wants to know the end of the flatten iterator but copy doesn't have a 4 iterator variant to provide it. There may be a way of adding 'this is a checked iterator' to flatten

Comment: It seems that adding `typedef iterator _Unchecked_type;` (potentially inside an `#ifdef`) to `flattening_iterator` will tell MSVC not to complain here