# Efficient way to do std::map comparison based on their values

Tags: c++

I have two maps which I want to compare based on values. The maps are of type:

```
std::map<std::string, CustomMap> compareMap;
```

where CustomMap is:

```
std::map<std::string, Struct> CustomMap;
```

and Struct is a struct of two strings. This is how the design is and I can't change it.

How do I efficiently compare two compareMaps based on their values? The only way I can think of now is to use 2 for loops. Is there some inbuilt way to compare the maps based on their values? Or some way to calculate the hash on the values and find out which entries differ and which entries are the same?

EDIT: Let me rephrase my question: Is there a better elegant way to compare the maps based on their values instead of using two for-loops? I know the maps are different and some keys have the same values in both the maps. I only want to know which keys have different values in the two maps.

P.S: I don't have C++11

Comment: Do you just want to know if `compareMap A` and `compareMap B` are equal?

Comment: "_Is there some inbuilt way to compare the maps based on their values?_" Why would there be inbuilt way for this, if such usage isn't intended usage of `std::map`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I know the maps are different and some keys have the same values in both the maps. I only want to know which keys have different values in the two maps.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes I see that now, I have rephrased my question, apologies

Comment: possibly `std::set_difference` with a custom comparator

Comment: Possibly `std::set_difference` with a [flattening iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623082/flattening-iterator)?

Comment: @NathanOliver and MooingDuck Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: What if map A contains a key not in map B, or vice versa?  Do you care about those or does that situation never arise?

Comment: I think you probably write the `for` loops making liberal use of comments (of course you thoroughly comment your code, right?) because anything "elegant" might may also be incomprehensible.

Comment: @Richard And most likely no more efficient.

Comment: @PaulSanders: And perhaps less-so, since cobbling together a bunch of library functions may produce, e.g., intermediate data structures.

Comment: @PaulSanders that scenario is already handled, just doing a find on the key. This is the scenario I'm yet to implement.

Comment: Not having C++11 makes this somewhat harder (no `auto`, no ranged `for` loops).  Is this a given?

Comment: @PaulSanders unfortunately yes